# H2 Oracle compatibility for RENAME COLUMN statement

Tags: oracle, h2

I am using Oracle for production and H2 as an in-memory test database.  I'm having trouble with Oracle compatibility for the "rename column" statement.

Specifically, the Oracle statement is:

alter table "SOME_TABLE" rename column "COLUMN_A" to "COLUMN_B" ;

I'm using Spring and Liquibase to set up the test environment and believe I have specified "use Oracle compatibility mode" correctly, but this statement is rejected by H2 as follows:

Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax error in SQL statement

```
"ALTER TABLE ""SOME_TABLE"" RENAME COLUMN[*] ""COLUMN_A"" TO ""COLUMN_B"" "; expected "TO"; SQL statement:
alter table "SOME_TABLE" rename column "COLUMN_A" to "COLUMN_B" [42001-174]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:332)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getSyntaxError(DbException.java:197)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.getSyntaxError(Parser.java:504)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.read(Parser.java:2867)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseAlterTable(Parser.java:4971)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseAlter(Parser.java:4412)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:316)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:289)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:265)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:226)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:437)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:380)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1138)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.executeInternal(JdbcStatement.java:168)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.execute(JdbcStatement.java:156)
    at   liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor$ExecuteStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcExecutor.java:294)
```

I am finding through research that this level of compatibility may not be implemented by H2 at this time.  Are there any extensions I can write or any other actions I can take to rename a column in both Oracle and H2.

Thanks!
Steve Nester

Comment: Another good example why testing against a different DBMS is not a good idea.

Comment: But if you are using Liquibase, then why don't you use the `<renameColumn>` tag? http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/rename_column.html it can deal with different DBMS

Comment: I'm a newb at Liquibase and modifying existing scripts - no xml files like this in our repo (yet).  But thanks, I'll look into some refactoring.  For now I just delete the old column and recreate the new one which is fine in this use case.  Thanks for the info.

Comment: Well, if you know you are targeting multiple DBMS you should use Liquibase's XML format as that gives you at least some abstraction layer and you only need a single changeSet

Comment: Thanks - I'll check into it - sounds like a better solution.